# Framed mini pages with shared inside border?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage, tabularx

So I have been trying to get two mini pages, side by side, in one box with a shared center border. The best I have gotten is

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage[paperwidth = 8.5in, paperheight=11in, top=.75in, bottom=.75in,                                 
    left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}


    \begin{document}
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
    \fbox{%
    \hspace{.5em}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
    \Large Objects
    \end{center}
    1)HH optimization objects \\
    $V(K,k)$\\
    $k^\prime(K,k)$\\
    \textbullet$c(K,k)$ \\
    \textbullet $\mathcal{l}(K,k)$\\
    \textbullet$n(K,k)$\\

    \vspace{4mm}
    2) Firms optimization objects 
    \end{minipage}%
    \vline
    \hspace{.5em}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\textwidth}
    \setlength{\parindent}{1pc}
    Given Blah Blah\\dsgsdg\\sdgsdg\\sgsdg
    \end{minipage}
    }
    \end{document}
```

Which produces
[image: MWE]
I think this is not too bad, and is certainly good enough for me, but I was wondering if anybody has any suggestions, comments, criticisms? (other than obviously adding vspace at the start and end of the mini pages).

So far I have also tried two individuals framed mini pages, but Latex puts space between their space. I could remove it with negative `hspace`but it didn't look quite right. I also cannot use one frame and have `fboxsep` > 0 because then the `vline` doesn't meet the frame.

I realize I can also do this with tabular and/or align, probably. I planned on having a list inside, though (not sure If I will anymore or not. Bullets and newlines seem to work alright for my purposes), which seemed more troublesome than this approach.

Also, perhaps beamer would be better to use? I am not familiar with it though (and don't have the time to look into it right now), so I did not use it

Comment: Why not use a `tabular` with `p` column type or `tabularx` with `X` columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `tabular` with `p` column or a `tabularx` with `X` column.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{report}
    \usepackage[paperwidth = 8.5in, paperheight=11in, top=.75in, bottom=.75in,
    left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}

    \begin{document}
    With \verb|tabularx|

    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|} \hline
    \centering \Large Objects & Given Blah Blah \\
    1)HH optimization objects \newline
    $V(K,k)$\newline
    $k^\prime(K,k)$\newline
    \textbullet$c(K,k)$ \newline
    \textbullet $\mathcal{l}(K,k)$\newline
    \textbullet$n(K,k)$\newline
    & dsgsdg\newline sdgsdg\newline sgsdg \\
    2) Firms optimization objects & \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}

    \bigskip
    With \verb|tabular|:

    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}
                    |p{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth\relax}|} \hline
    \centering \Large Objects & Given Blah Blah \\
    1)HH optimization objects \newline
    $V(K,k)$\newline
    $k^\prime(K,k)$\newline
    \textbullet$c(K,k)$ \newline
    \textbullet $\mathcal{l}(K,k)$\newline
    \textbullet$n(K,k)$\newline
    & dsgsdg\newline sdgsdg\newline sgsdg \\
    2) Firms optimization objects & \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And may be you need an `enumerate` and `itemize` in the first column which I didn't touch.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that I could `\newline` in the same column continually and then go to the second column. I was doing one line with 2 columns, second line with 2 columns, and so on, which lead to problems/was annoying because everything on the left was single-line and on the right was multi-line for what I was doing.